# Add a captions to integrated FlexSlider on Wordpress Organictheme.

Tags: wordpress, flexslider, caption

Would like to add a caption to FlexSlider, which is integrated into a purchased Wordpress Organictheme.  I believe the slideshow page code must be modified and though I have found some similar issues here, I have not figured out (after many hours and failed attempts) where and what exactly to add to the existing code.  Seems like captions should be a no-brainer!  Seems like they should somehow be included within the

tags???  Would REALLY APPRECIATE  some help.  html, but NOT php literate. THANK YOU!

The code needs to go somewhere in here:

```
            <div class="flexslider">

                <ul class="slides">

                    <?php $data = array(
                        'post_parent'       => $post->ID,
                        'post_type'         => 'attachment',
                        'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
                        'order'             => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                        'numberposts'       => -1
                    ); ?>

                    <?php 
                    $images = get_posts($data); foreach( $images as $image ) { 
                        $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);              echo '<li><img src="'.$imageurl.'"  /></li>' . "\n"; 
                    } ?>

                </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, indeed.

I'll answer this in case someone else needs it. The two missing bits of code are:

```
<p class="flex-caption"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>
```

... required by flexslider to display the captions, and

```
$caption = $image->post_excerpt;
```

... to actually obtain the captions. New code would be:

```
        <div class="flexslider">

            <ul class="slides">

                <?php $data = array(
                    'post_parent'       => $post->ID,
                    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
                    'order'             => 'ASC',
                    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
                    'numberposts'       => -1
                ); ?>

                <?php 
                $images = get_posts($data);
                foreach( $images as $image ) { 
                    $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
                    $caption = $image->post_excerpt;
                    echo '<li><img src="'.$imageurl.'"  /><p class="flex-caption">'.$caption.'</p></li>' . "\n";
                } ?>

            </ul>

        </div>
```