# WordPress Integrated FlexSlider not showing captions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

Before anyone links me to this [EXTREMELY similar (if not identical) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579510/add-a-captions-to-integrated-flexslider-on-wordpress-organictheme), the answer provided there does not work with my code.

I'm attempting to do everything via a function as found [here](http://www.premiumdw.com/2014/04/22/create-a-flexslider-gallery-using-attachment-images-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add captions if and ONLY if the attached image has one let alone how to access the attached image's caption.
I have a feeling [`wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js) is the way to go in accessing the attached image's caption, but I'm so new at writing functions I don't even know how to utilize it within my existing function.

My current functions.php:

```
//Add Flexslider
function add_flexslider() { 

    global $post; 

    $attachments = get_children ( array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        ));

    if ($attachments) { 

        echo '<div class="flexslider">';
        echo '<ul class="slides">';

        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) { 

            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'large');
            //if statement that shows the caption only if attached image has one
            echo '<p class="flex-caption">';
            //somehow get attached image's caption. perhaps with wp_prepare_attatchment_for_js()?
            echo '</p>';
            //end if caption statement
            echo '</li>';

        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this...[`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) is one of them:

```
$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );
$caption = $metadata ? $metadata['image_meta']['caption'] : '';

echo $caption;
```

However, if you're referring to the caption set in the Admin, you'll want to use the `post_excerpt`:

```
$attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
$caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;

echo $caption;
```

Comment: IF it has a caption.. that's a lazy way to do a ternary anyway. `$caption = !empty($metadata['image_meta']['caption']) ? $metadata['image_meta']['caption'] : '';`

Comment: should probably use a if/else and check if it's set and is array, etc

Comment: @Pamblam , the expression I wrote is fine...`$metadata` can only be `false` or an `array` of attachment meta.

Comment: no, `wp_get_attachment_metadata` can only be et cetera et cetera.. `$metadata` can be whatever he sets it to.

Comment: i'm just being picky. your example is fine.

Comment: We're talking about `$metadata`, which has been set to the return value of `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`.

Comment: @mevius I'm referring to the caption set in the admin. the `post_excerpt` isn't working for me. Just to test if any random text echoed after <p> would work...it does, so I know it's not in the styling anywhere. I also tried `echo wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $attachment->caption );` with no avail.

Comment: also if I use `post_excerpt` and the post has a manually entered excerpt already, wouldn't it return the manually entered post excerpt as opposed to the image caption?

Comment: No, because you're passing `$attachment_id` to `get_post()`...There's no reason this shouldn't work, unless you've added HTML to the image caption.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. I've put the code you wrote into my function and two things happen if I put the variable in the if statement: 1. I get an error "Undefined variable: attachment_id" 2. the page's manually entered excerpt appears. If I place the variables into the foreach, NOTHING happens.

Comment: Are you putting my code (all 3 lines of it) after `echo '<p class="flex-caption">';`?

Comment: No, I wasn't. Okay. Now that I did that the caption does appear, however I still receive an error message: "Undefined variable: attachment_id" I have my wordpress in debug mode when the error appears. When I'm not in debug mode the page looks normal. Not sure why I'm getting the error in debug...?

Comment: The error should give you a line number to look at. If you still can't figure out what the issue is, I recommend closing up this question and asking a new one.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help and patience. Means a lot to a beginner.